# ¿es posible realizar una base de datos documental en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, nosql

Dentro del MySQL 5.7 en adelante hasta la versión 8; ya estamos en posibilidad de usar atributos para datos de tipo `JSON`

De este modo:

```
CREATE TABLE profile(
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  attributes JSON NOT NULL
);
```

Posteriormente para hacer la inserción de datos, hacemos lo siguiente

```
INSERT INTO profile(name, attributes)
VALUES
('alfred', '{"data": {"backend": true, "frontend": "maybe"}}')
```

Algunas funciones como `JSON_EXTRACT()` me permiten leer los datos de tipo `JSON` de este modo

```
SELECT name, JSON_EXTRACT(attributes, '$.data') AS Data FROM profile;
```

Si por ejemplo deseamos leer el valor de una clave específica de nuestra estructura JSON podemos hacer lo siguiente

> La sintáxis siguiente es el equivalente de `JSON_EXTRACT` tiene la
>   misma funcionalidad pero la estructura esta acortada; otro detalle es
>   que por ejemplo

1. `->>` ayuda a eliminar las comillas de las cadenas de texto que de los valores resulten
2. `->` muestra el resultado pero incluye en el mismo las comillas en la cadena de texto

   SELECT name, attributes->'$.data.backend' AS Data FROM profile;

Sin embargo lo anterior sigue bajo la consigna de usar `SQL` aunque las `JSON_FUNCTIONS()` permiten operar los datos con mayor flexibilidad

Aquí la fuente: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-function-reference.html

Pero la pregunta es la siguiente:

**¿Puedo crear una base de datos documental tal cual me lo permite por ejemplo MongoDB?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde la versión 8 de MySQL podemos hacer uso de la `mysql 8 shell` que se instala por separado que nos permite usar a MySQL como un **document store engine**

> (es importante recalcar que solo funciona la versión 8 y
>   debemos descargar dicha shell por separado) por ejemplo en Windows con
>   ayuda de MySQL Installer

*Una vez abierta la shell de mysql 8, nos conectamos del modo siguiente*

```
\connect root@localhost/ejemplo
```

Donde ejemplo, es el nombre de una base de datos vacía creada de manera tradicional

Ahora necesitamos crear nuestra primer colección a la cual vamos a llamar `movies`; del modo siguiente

```
db.createCollection('movies')
```

db es una variable de tipo global que se asigna como valor el nombre del schema elegido, en este caso `movies`

Ahora para insertar el primer registro ejecutamos el siguiente comando

```
db.movies.add({ "name": "avengers 4", "cool": true })
```

Lo cual nos debe devolver un valor como el siguiente

```
Query OK, 1 item affected (0.3737 sec)
```

Para leer el registro recién guardado hacemos lo siguiente

```
db.movies.find()
```

Que nos debería mostrar algo como lo siguiente

```
[
    {
        "_id": "00005ba7b33c0000000000000001",
        "name": "avengers 4",
        "year": 2018
    }
]
1 document in set (0.0012 sec)
```

Si por ejemplo deseamos modificar el valor de alguna clave del registro recién ingresado hacemos lo siguiente

```
db.movies.modify("name = 'avengers 4'").set("cool", false)
```

Finalmente para borrar un registro de manera permanente hacemos el siguiente comando

```
db.movies.remove("name = 'avengers 4'")
```

Por último si deseamos eliminar la colección llamada movies por completo basta con ejecutar el siguiente comando

```
db.dropCollection('movies')
```

Por ejemplo desde la línea de comandos podemos hacer lo siguiente

`show tables;` (dentro de la base de datos ejemplo)

Que nos mostrará lo siguiente

```
+-------------------+
| Tables_in_ejemplo |
+-------------------+
| movies            |
+-------------------+
```

Si ahora hago un `SELECT *` de la tabla movies, tendré un resultado semejante a este

```
mysql> select * from movies;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
| doc                                                                   | _id                          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
| {"_id": "00005ba7b33c0000000000000004", "age": 29, "name": "alfredo"} | 00005ba7b33c0000000000000004 |
| {"_id": "00005ba7b33c0000000000000005", "age": 35, "name": "danel"}   | 00005ba7b33c0000000000000005 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Aquí una referencia oficial: https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/document_store.html

Añado información respecto al tema de índices, su creación y eliminación en las colecciones

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-shell-tutorial-python-documents-index.html

Comment: está interesante la interfaz de línea de comando. Claramente intenta replicar la sintaxis de MongoDB (que en realidad es más que nada JS) pero encontré deceptionante la sintaxis para modificar. Debiera ser `db.movies.find({"name" : "avengers 4"}).set({"cool", false});`  en el fondo ese modify tiene adentro una cláusula WHERE de SQL tradicional, y con eso no están ofreciendo lo mejor de los dos mundos, sino mezclando conceptos.  A todo esto, esas colecciones se ven en phpmyadmin?

Comment: @amenadiel si de hecho puedes hacer un show tables a la base de datos ejemplo, que fue la que hice en mi caso y aparecerá la colección movies

Comment: pero  con phpmyadmin o con el cliente normal, qué pasa si haces `SELECT * FROM movies`? Será una tabla de una sola columna de tipo json?

Comment: deja agrego información al respecto en la respuesta @amenadiel

Comment: También buscaría información respecto de los índices. En PostreSQL se demoraron en optimizar los índices de tipo GIN para JSON y JSONB. Además, cuando seteas un registro en realidad no es atómico. Lees el registro, le cambias una llave, lo actualizas completo. Creo que no hay cómo saber si MySQL hace lo mismo y el CLI sólo provee sintactic sugar para que no se note